# get string from Text Object using Animation Nodes

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

Is it possible to pull in the actual string of text from a Text Object? It's easy to create a string of text in the nodes and send it out to a Text Object, or even to pull in text from an external file...I just can't figure out how to get it from a Text Object that I created manually. I thought I might be able to using the Object Attribute Input node, but I don't know if that's possible. When I copy the data path to "Body Text", it just gives me "body", which doesn't work...

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.body` attribute is not an attribute of the object, but of the text object data. So you need to get the attribute like this:

[image]

An object is like a container for multiple things that gives them properties like location, scale, render visibility, etc. These things range from meshes, lights, curves, .. and texts. And what is inside the object is referred to as `data`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple like this, I just wasn't sure of the syntax.